# Trying to find out how many years between unix timestamps?

Tags: php, unix-timestamp

I found some examples when searching, but couldn't find an example to show how many years are in-between unix timestamps.

I tried the following code:

```
$bought = $row['purchase_date'];
$sold = $row['sold_date'];
$duration = ($bought - $sold);
$years_owned = date("Y", $duration);

echo $years_owned;
```

Though I only got the echo result of the current year of 2023. The timestamps are from 2018 through 2023 so I was expecting the echo to show 4.7 years (when rounded up) based on the exact timestamps which are:

bought = 1539320400
sold = 1687179600

I then tried this and it worked but it will only give me 5 years as a result and not the exact amount of years in decimal format:

```
$bought = date("Y",$row['purchase_date']);
$sold = date("Y",$row['sold_date']);
$duration = ($bought - $sold);
$years_owned = $duration;

echo $years_owned;
```

Which gave me 5 years but not the 4.7 I was looking for and I expected that result. I would like to get the exact number of how long I owned something before selling it. A lot of search results are asking about seconds or days and I need the years.

Comment: You could subtract the seconds, then divide by the number of seconds in a year and round up to one decimal. Note that there are 31557600 seconds in a year, see: https://www.rapidtables.com/calc/time/seconds-in-year.html

Comment: Ah perfect yes I already got the result :D  Thanks I used `$duration = ($bought - $sold);
   $seconds_in_a_year = 31536000;
   
   $years_owned = ($duration/$seconds_in_a_year);`

Comment: I would go for the Julian astronomical year, with 31557600 seconds. It will make little difference, but it is probably the best choice.

Comment: Thanks again.  I also had to use abs() to make the result positive

Comment: _"Which gave me 5 years but not the 4.7 I was looking for"_ - of course you can't expect anything but an integer value, when you work with the `Y` date formatter.